# xml_http.onreadystatechange is not a function

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to get over ajax request, but Chrome console shows me this message:
xml_http.onreadystatechange is not a function

Here is my JS code:

```
function ajax_request () {
            var xml_http = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xml_http.onreadystatechange(function () {
                if(xml_http.readyState == 4 && xml_http.status == 200){
                    var result = document.getElementById('result');
                    result.innerHTML = xml_http.responseText;
                }
            });
            xml_http.open('GET', 'data.php', true);
            xml_http.send();
        }
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<button onclick="ajax_request();">Click</button>
    <div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign a function to onreadystatechange, not call it as a function while passing another as an argument.

```
xml_http.onreadystatechange = function () { ... };
```

Answer (score 0):

Can u try this

```
function ajax_request () {
            var xml_http = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xml_http.onreadystatechange = function () { 
                if(xml_http.readyState == 4 && xml_http.status == 200){
                    var result = document.getElementById('result');
                    result.innerHTML = xml_http.responseText;
                }
            }
            xml_http.open('GET', 'data.php', true);
            xml_http.send();
        }


<button onclick="ajax_request();">Click</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
xml_http.onreadystatechange=function () {
            if(xml_http.readyState == 4 && xml_http.status == 200){
                var result = document.getElementById('result');
                result_data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
                result.innerHTML = result_data;
            }
        }
```

You have to parse the JSON data before you can use.